# Search for text in an array nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, foreach

I have the following data

```
let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('test.json');
let orders = JSON.parse(rawdata);
```

Rawdata data looks like this

```
[{"order":["Awaiting delivery","Order date: Dec 18, 2022","Order ID: 11111111","Copy","Order details","store name","product name","1, 1","US $1.73x1","Total: US $5.39","Confirm receipt","Track order"]},{"order":["Awaiting delivery","Order date: Dec 18, 2022","Order ID: 2222222","Copy","Order details","store name_2","5","items","Total: US $13.07","Confirm receipt","Track order"]}]
```

What I'm trying to do is to extract the order's date, and order's total.
So far I wrote the following code:

```
orders.forEach(element => {
let order_date = element.order[1].replace('Order date:', '')
let order_ID = element.order[2].replace('Order ID:', '')
let store_name = element.order[5]
for (i=0; i<15; i++) {
    if (element.order[i].includes('Total')) {
        let order_total = element.order[i]
    }
}
console.log(order_date + "*" + order_ID + "*" + store_name + "*" + order_total)
});
```

I'm not able to extract the order's total because I receive the error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')`
I also tried to use .contains() but it doesn't work either.

The expected results from the console.log would be something like this:

```
Dec 18, 2022*11111111*store name*Total: US $5.39
Dec 18, 2022*2222222*store name_2*Total: US $13.07
```

Could you please help me to understand what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Can you put your expected result?

Comment: Just added the expected results... I tried everything but looping each element doesn't seem to work while I'm searching if an element includes string "Total"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('test.json');

let orders = JSON.parse(rawdata);

orders.forEach(element => {
let order_date = element.order[1].replace('Order date:', '')
let order_ID = element.order[2].replace('Order ID:', '')
let store_name = element.order[5]
let order_total = 0
for (i=0; i<element.order.length; i++) {
    if (element.order[i].includes('Total')) {
        order_total = element.order[i]
    }
}
console.log(order_date + "*" + order_ID + "*" + store_name + "*" + order_total)    
});
```

length not up to 15 user element.length and just one change in order raw data it is invalid add [ so it look like

[{"order":["Awaiting delivery","Order date: Dec 18, 2022","Order ID: 11111111","Copy","Order details","store name","product name","1, 1","US $1.73x1","Total: US $5.39","Confirm receipt","Track order"]},{"order":["Awaiting delivery","Order date: Dec 18, 2022","Order ID: 2222222","Copy","Order details","store name_2","5","items","Total: US $13.07","Confirm receipt","Track order"]}]

Comment: Thanks bro! found the issue... I just had to change 'Let order_total' to simply 'order_total' and it worked... thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')` means you're trying to read element outside of the bounds of the Array. Try looping over the actual length like this :

```
for (i=0; i<element.order.length; i++) {
    if (element.order[i].includes('Total')) {
        let order_total = element.order[i]
    }
}
```

and your error should disappear.